# TOTP (MFA) implementation

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication, totp

I am building a project in react while using aws cognito and aws amplify,
I am also using google as an external service provider, means the client can log in with his google account, the authentication is auto using the aws cognito and I am trying to implement a TOTP during log in / sign up.
From some reason when i define this in the user in the aws cognito (that i want to use TOTP) its givving me an error that I do not know how to deal with.
I am attaching images of the problem in the user setting in the cognito (user itself, not the userpool).

[image: MFA settings page]
[image: Details of the error]

Thank you.

I already check the config of the Amplify and in the cognito, nothing sees unusual.
[image: user pool setting]